# How to make close button open a new form on Delphi

Tags: delphi

I need that "x" button on any form would not close the form but instead open another 3 random forms on delphi, i have no idea how to do that, please help

Comment: Sounds like [nagware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shareware#Nagware) or similar which nobody would want on free will - what do you want to achieve through this?

Comment: @AmigoJack you never know what some customer wants to achieve with such a request.

Comment: @AmigoJack i need to make a joke programm that will pop up 3 random images when closing one. this is the project for university. I didnt want to disrespect anyone or anything like that. Sorry if i did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the form's [`OnCloseQuery`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.OnCloseQuery) event to detect the user's trying to close your form (by clicking the close button in the top-right corner, by double-clicking the form's title bar icon, by selecting the Close system menu item, by pressing Alt+F4, etc.).

Then set `CanClose` to `False` and instead open your three new forms:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  CanClose := False;
  Form2.Show;
  Form3.Show;
  Form4.Show;
end;
```

Comment: However, I might add that this behaviour is very non-standard and may confuse the user.

Comment: I would not encourage helping here, no matter how easy it is.

Comment: @AmigoJack: That's a very valid point.  At least I tried to piggy-back some Win32 education on the actual issue.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand that is the point. i need to make a joke programm that will pop up 3 random images when closing one. this is the project for university. I didnt want to disrespect anyone or anything like that. Also appreciate the answer, thank you very much.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Note that this approach will also block system reboot/shutdown, as the `OnCloseQuery` event is fired during `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` handling.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [@AndreasRejbrand's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72317285/65863), you could use the Form's `OnCloseQuery` event. But, the problem with that approach is that the event is also triggered during system reboot/shutdown, and you don't want to block that.  If `OnCloseQuery` returns `CanClose=False` during a system shutdown, the shutdown is canceled.

Another option is to use the Form's `OnClose` event instead, setting its `Action` parameter to `caNone`, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caNone;
  Form2.Show;
  Form3.Show;
  Form4.Show;
end;
```

However, the best option would to be to handle only *user-initiated* closures (the `X` button, `ALT-F4`, etc) by having the Form handle the [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand) message looking for `SC_CLOSE` notifications, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if (Message.Msg = WM_SYSCOMMAND) and (Message.WParam and $FFF0 = SC_CLOSE) then
  begin
    Message.Result := 0;
    Form2.Show;
    Form3.Show;
    Form4.Show;
  end
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

This way, *system-initiated* closures are unhindered.

Comment: I appreciate the input! I really do! Thanks! But in my case blocking system shutdown is a good thing. Thank you for detailed explanation!